# Create FTP account in Cpanel - without domain

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel, whm

I have been using this script to create FTP accounts very successfully

```
// your cPanel username
$cpanel_user = 'usernam';

// your cPanel password
$cpanel_pass = 'password';

// your cPanel skin
$cpanel_skin = 'x3';

// your cPanel domain
$cpanel_host = 'domain.com';

// ftp username
$ftp_user = 'user';

 // ftp password
$ftp_pass = 'ftp_password';

// ftp home directory
$ftp_home = 'home';

// ftp quota
$ftp_quota = '0';

// create the ftp account
$request = "http://{$cpanel_user}:{$cpanel_pass}@{$cpanel_host}:2082";
$request .= "/frontend/{$cpanel_skin}/ftp/doaddftp.html";
$request .= "?login={$ftp_user}";
$request .= "&password={$ftp_pass}";
$request .= "&homedir=public_html/{$ftp_user}";
//$request .= "a={$ftp_quota}";
$result = file_get_contents($request);
echo $result;
?>
```

But this assumes that I have the domain pointed to the hosting. I am wanting to have this script work with a domain that is not pointed to a domain yet.

Example: http://123.456.78.910~user/

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up that IP address and the cPanel port, you can login with any user account. So just set the IP address in `$cpanel_host` instead of the domain, for now. It'll create it, since you can access cPanel through (following your example IP) http://123.456.78.910:2082, and you could login just as though it were through the domain itself.

Comment: I tried that before and it did not work, I think I had the password slightly incorrect.

Works now!!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Tried and Tested...

You need to enter variables

```
$cpaneluser = Your cpanel username
$cpanelpass = Your cpanel password
$domain = your domain name ( xyz.com )
$fuser = ftp username
$fpass = ftp password
$homedir = ftp directory
```

---

```
$url = "http://$cpaneluser:$cpanelpass@$domain:2082/json-api/cpanel?";
$url .= "cpanel_jsonapi_version=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Ftp&cpanel_jsonapi_func=addftp&";
$url .= "user=$fuser&pass=$fpass&homedir=$fhomedir&quota=0";

var_dump($url);
$result = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($result === FALSE) 
die("ERROR: FTP Account not created. Please make sure you passed correct parameters.");
echo $result;
```

hope it helps..